# Subclassing UIScrollView for drawing w/o views

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I'm contemplating subclassing UIScrollView (the way UITextView does) to draw a fairly large amount of text (formatted in ways that NSTextView can't).

So far the view won't actually scroll. I'm setting contentSize, and when I drag, I see the scroll indicator. But nothing changes (and I don't get a drawRect: message).

An alternate approach is to use a child view, and I've done this. The view can be over 5000 pixels high, however, and I'm a bit concerned about performance on an actual device.

(The other approach, be like UITableView, would be a huge pain -- I'm "porting" Mac Cocoa code, and a collection of views would be a huge architecture change.)

I've done some searching, but haven't found anyone who is using UIScrollView to do the drawing. Has anyone done this and know of any pitfalls?

Comment: Why not format the text in HTML and use a UIWebView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that UIScrollView does when the user scrolls is update its bounds rectangle, which causes the scroll views subviews to move. You could try setting the scroll view's `contentMode` to `UIViewContentModeRedraw`. From the docs:

> `UIViewContentModeRedraw`
>   Redisplays the view when the bounds change by invoking the setNeedsDisplay method.

Comment: That seems to do the trick, thanks! (Now to do some profiling…)